# 'Calloc' could not allocate memory When trying to Knit an RMD file into an HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown, sqldf

I am trying to knit an RMD file into an HTML report using a pretty large dataset (2,600,000 rows with 18 columns) and I keep getting a memory error on the same line of code... Here is the full error:

> Quitting from lines 148-149 (banking_complaint_R_report.Rmd)
> Error in gsub("[\n]{2,}$", "\n", x) :
> 'Calloc' could not allocate memory (18446744071562067968 of 1 bytes)
> Calls:  ... lapply -> FUN -> sew.character -> comment_out -> gsub
> Execution halted

This is my code on line 148-149:

```
sqldf("SELECT columnX, COUNT(*) AS total FROM my_data GROUP BY columnX ORDER BY total DESC")
```

I already tried searching this error and found a solution to increase my memory allocation with the `memory.limit(size=100000)` that I typed directly into the R studio console. but I still am getting the same above error when I try to Knit into an HTML file. I also tried restarting my computer without opening any other applications and still getting the error...

I should also note that when I run all the code chunks individually it works so just the Knit into an HTML seems to be the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit the queries to the top 10 results using the LIMIT 10 in my sqldf statements. I had some queries that had over 60K rows and I guess the system couldn't handle it and also is not very efficient for the knit file. So narrowing the query to the top results was the only way I found to knit my code.